# .netcore-mvc app will not target 2.1.3 after VS forced update to 2.1.4

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I started developing a new website prior to .net core framework 2.1.4 was released, we got our production environment all set up with "Coming Soon" pages, etc.

As this server hosts other sites, we do not want to restart for an upgrade to 2.1.4, so I updated the csproj file with

```
    <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>2.1.3</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
```

I also checked the NuGet packages for Microsoft.NETCore.App and it is set to 2.1.3

Yet, when I publish the site and copy it to the folder on the host, it still logs

> It was not possible to find any compatible framework version The
>   specified framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '2.1.4' was not
>   found.
>     - Check application dependencies and target a framework version installed at:
>         "PATH"
>     - Installing .NET Core prerequisites might help resolve this problem:
>         http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409
>     - The .NET Core framework and SDK can be installed from:
>         https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
>     - The following versions are installed:
>         1.0.4 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
>         1.1.1 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
>         2.1.2 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
>         2.1.3 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]

I am at a loss as to what to do, how do I change this project to target 2.1.3 instead of 2.1.4??

CSProj:

```
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>2.1.3</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" Version="4.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Linq.Dynamic.Core" Version="1.0.8.18" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Screenshot of Nuget dependencies in VS:
[Screenshot of Dependencies in VS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiR39.png)

Comment: Have you installed Net Core 2.1.4?

Comment: It was previously installed, but due to us wanting to downgrade back to 2.1.3 it has been uninstalled, causing this issue. I can not install it on the production machine as it would cause downtime that we are trying to avoid.

Comment: Well, that is bad, you need to install 2.1.4 before using it, also, you should be able to run 2.1.3 with the 2.1.4 installed with no problems, i would strongly recommend to start using docker to avoid that kind of problems in the future

Comment: My issue is downgrading the project to 2.1.3 if that is unclear, I apologize... I understand 2.1.4 can run 2.1.3, but I want to make my project target 2.1.3 and am unsure how to do so.

Comment: Ok, yes, i was missunderstanding a little, just check your nuget dependencies, all should point 2.1.3, it is the only place were the version is defined. On the other hand, i would really recommend to update to 2.1.4, since the only reason that exists is to fix a NEt Core vulnerability that could cause you a Denial Of Service, more info here https://github.com/dotnet/Announcements/issues/83

Comment: I am targeting Microsoft.NETCore.App version 2.1.3 but still getting the above error

Comment: Could you update your question with your csproj? just to be sure

Comment: Add the version to the dependency  "<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.1.3" />"

Comment: Adding the version to the dependency did not change the result, still logging the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying to downgrade for 2 days, I decided to stay up and deploy 2.1.4 to the production server during customer off hours, I know this isn't technically the "answer" but it was the only way I could solve the issue within the 4 day time window that it needed to be deployed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems weird to me, the only thing that we need to change the NetCore version in our proiject, is to change the csproj between versions, for example, this is a csproj of one of out projects running in 2.1.4:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>false</PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>
    <DockerComposeProjectPath>..\docker-compose.dcproj</DockerComposeProjectPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="wwwroot\**" />
    <Content Remove="wwwroot\**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="wwwroot\**" />
    <None Remove="wwwroot\**" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    ...
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.1.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="2.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.1.4" />
    ...
  </ItemGroup>

  ...

</Project>
```

And we can downgrade it to 2.1.3 by simply changing that two dependencies

```
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.1.3" />
```

I can see that we are not using your directive `<RuntimeFrameworkVersion>2.1.3</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>`

I do not know if that could make any difference.

On the other hand, it would be interesting to know what made you want to go back, since there are no significant changes in the last update, and it is a very necessary one, since it is to [fix a vulnerability](http://github.com/dotnet/Announcements/issues/83) that could cause you a DOS.

Since the update cycle of dot net core is going to be in very short periods of time and the downtime is a really concern, i also would strongly recommend that you start to use Docker, that could allow you to run several environmnents (2.1, 2.1.2...) in the same docker.

We even hit a bug with core 2.1, so we are runnning a separate container with only one feature in net core 2.0, while our app is happy running in the same server our app in 2.1.4

Also, be sure to make a clean & build, you could try even delete the obj and bin folders manually, just to be sure there is nothing causing you that error

Comment: I am going to attempt to backtrack in source control and work from there and see if I can fix the issue that way, as these changes to my csproj file don't seem to be doing the trick. Will report back once I do so.

Comment: Yes, also, does this happen in your dev machine?, in the server or in both?, that could give you some clues, from that, I can not tell what else could be, sorry, hope you fin a solution and share it here

Comment: I am deploying to a dev server, locally I can run it in IISExpress, even though 2.1.4 is not installed, but remotely it still spits out the error.

Comment: Welp, pulled down a project that was targeting 2.1.3 (as it is currently deployed to production with that runtime) added my views, models, and controllers + the necessary routes to startup.cs and I STILL get the error saying it needs 2.1.4, I am at a loss for this.

Comment: Are you building in the server?, on local? do you have the runtime installed or the sdk?, also, reconsider docker, is going to help with this kind of problems

Comment: I run locally using IIS Express, runtime locally is 2.1.3, same as server. I Publish to a folder locally, then copy to the server. I have both the SDK and runtime installed locally, only the runtime is installed on the server though.

I am not in a position in my company that can install docker on a production host or even make it happen, I can simply work with what I am given.